# PyQt5 - pythonw.exe crash on handling clicked event

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I'm new to PyQt5 and I've got an error (pythonw.exe not working anymore) with the following code:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication
```

class Example(QWidget):

```
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):               

    qbtn = QPushButton('Quit', self)
    qbtn.clicked.connect(self.q)
    qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
    qbtn.move(50, 50)       

    self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
    self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
    self.show()

def q():
    print('test')
    sys.exit()
```

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    app.exec_()

First it works, but only until I push the "quit" button. Then the error message pops up.
If I put the q() function outside the class (and change "self.q" into "q") it works fine.
What's the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Windows 7
Python 3.4.3 (x86)
PyQt 5.5.1 (x86)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that's because when `q()` is inside the class it's expects a compulsory argument as the first parameter, this is usually called `self` and is passed for you implicitly by python when you're calling the method (`q()` not `q(self)`). just as you've done with the `initUI` method in your class, when you put it outside the class, it's just a normal function and not a method again (function in a class), so it's fine to define the function without `self`

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QPushButton, QApplication
from PyQt5.QtCore import QCoreApplication

class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):               
        qbtn = QPushButton('Quit', self)
        qbtn.clicked.connect(self.q)
        qbtn.resize(qbtn.sizeHint())
        qbtn.move(50, 50)       

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 250, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Quit button')    
        self.show()

    def q(self):
        print('test')
        sys.exit()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Also next time make sure you properly indent your code properly after pasting it (if the formatting gets messed up for some reason) and include any error messages you're getting (it encourages others to help you)...instead of just saying 'the error' or 'an error'

Comment: thanks for your help, it worked fine. i had some formatting problems while using the "pre" and "code" tags, the last part just became normal text so i had the indent it to post the question, i didnt know how to fix it else, sorry

Comment: Note that to properly close a window on clicking a button you should use `self.close()` instead of `sys.exit()`